# Storing any data type in container inside another container

Tags: c++, templates, types, polymorphism

I need to have a container inside other container that stores any type of data:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<std::any>> vectors(5);
```

I need to use vector methods on any element of outer vector in loop, like:

```cpp
for (auto innerVector: vectors) {
    // innerVector.erase(innerVector.begin() + 2);
    // this means that i can't declare "vectors" as:
    // std::vector<std::any> vectors(5);
    // because i would have to do any_cast for each element of outer vector
    // which as far as i understand would not be possible 
    // because we need to pass template parameter unknown at compile time
}
```

But I also need fast iteration:

```cpp
for (auto element : vectors[0]) {
    // cast element using std::any_cast<T>(element)
    // call method of element: element.specificMethod()

    // this means I can't declare "vectors" as:
    // std::vector<std::vector<std::any>> vectors(5);
    // because I would have to cast every element. 
    // which would be very slow. any_cast performs runtime checks
}
```

Another option is to use polymorphism
with untemplated base class, which should declare pure virtual functions, like `erase()`,
but it would mean that I have to rewrite a lot of methods.
Additionally introducing some indirection and function calls
whose goal would be just to call the corresponding function of underlying container.

Are there any better ways about this?

Comment: Do you need to operate on the data? If so an abstract base class may be an option, there is also std::variant. Can you describe what kind of data you have and what you need to do with it. Because at the moment you only describe the "HOW" but not "WHAT"

Comment: @PepijnKramer I want to create simple EntityComponentSystem
So, I need to perform some operations on containers, like removing elements, iterating through them - using containers interface. When i want to do something with data itself (that can be of any type), i would do that with templates, like:
template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType& getComponent(Entity entity) {

}

Comment: Hmm so you still need to know up-front which datatypes you're going to be able how to handle right? Then maybe std::variant/std::visit is an option. But I don't have any real practical experience with EntityComponentSystem's so probably you best wait for somebody elses answer. Or lookup designs online for such existing systems at least to get some inspiration (that's what I would do)

Comment: AFAIK polymorphism is still more performant than using `std::any`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer kind of know types, yeah, but i wanted system itself to not be tied to any types, and just be a container, because system itself doesn't interact with components (data stored in container). System only interacts with it's containers, like vectors. But std variant can't be initialised using template arguments, right?

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your requirements. First, you want an outer container that "stores any type of data". However, your second code block would assume that `vectors[0]` is a container of some sort. Furthermore, the same code block assumes that the elements of the inner container have a `specificMethod` method. This is a far cry from "any type of data". Use these requirements to narrow down the role of your outer container.

Comment: Why do you need a vector of disparate vectors? Can't you define a structure?